# IBM developerworks tutorial advice

Tags: docker, docker-compose, soapui

Hello i am trying to complete the IBM tutorial for blockchain.

However, i am stuck at the "Deploy and run a java chaincode example'part 3, when using SoapUI.
SoapUI is unable to connect to the docker server. Pls help!!

Trying to test run.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96hER.png) Error logs for SoapUI.
[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrtiy.png) The docker container that i am using.
[image]

Comment: add some code and ask clear question on what you have tried and what is the issue

Comment: Sorry, i was editing the post trying to make it more clear.

Comment: not an issue..also instead of adding error screenshots, add your logs in the question itself..

Comment: included the logs please remove the downvote :( thank you

Comment: add error text in the question..not the screenshot